# Find MAX using type in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

First, I defined type for finding max value.

```
type my_val = NUM of int
           | PLUS of my_val * val
           | MULT of my_val * val
           | MAX of my_val list
```

Therefore, `MAX [NUM 9, NUM 20, NUM 3]` should be 20. That's what I wanted to do...

I should make a function which computes the result of `val`'s computation...

Here's what I wrote.

```
let rec eval: my_val -> int = fun given ->
    match given with
    | NUM i -> i
    | PLUS (i, j) -> eval(i) + eval(j)
    | MULT (i, j) -> eval(i) * eval(j)
    | MAX i -> 
                (match i with
                | [] -> 0
                | my_hd::[] -> eval(my_hd)
                | my_hd::my_tl -> if eval(my_hd) < eval(my_tl.hd) then eval(my_tl)
                                  else eval(my_hd::my_tl.tl))
```

The problem occurs in `my_hd < my_tl.hd` line.

It gives me this error.

> Unbound recored field hd

I guess that's because I tried to compare values of my_tl.hd, whose type is my_val?

But I couldn't think of the other way to solve this issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OCaml, `.` when applied to a variable name means record access. `my_tl.hd` means you're trying to access the record field `hd` of the record `my_tl`. The compiler tells you that this won't work because there is no record field called `hd` in scope. `my_tl` also isn't a record of course, but the compiler hasn't gotten that far yet.

What you seem to want to use instead is the `List.hd` function, and later the `List.tl` function. I would however recommend against using these as they're unsafe. If given an empty list they will blow up.

Instead you might want to use a pattern to extract the first *two* elements from the list:

```
  | my_hd1::my_hd2::my_tl ->
    if eval(my_hd1) < eval(my_hd2) then
      eval(my_hd2 :: my_tl)
    else
      eval(i)
```

This will never fail, and if you forget to cover the case of just one element the compiler will tell you.

Finally, using `i` and `j` as variable names for values that are not counters will get you lots of weird looks. `a` and `b`, or `x` and `y` are more commonly used as a short-hand if you have several "primary" values of the same type, but in this case you should really use more descriptive names.

Edit: Also, you should still not use parentheses for function application. That's just going to confuse you further when at some point you add another argument like you're used to, and get weird type errors.

Comment: Thanks. But `eval(my_hd2::my_tl)` gives me this error. `Error: This variant expression is expected to have type expr. The constructor :: does not belong to type expr`

Comment: Right, that's a type error following from your own code. `eval` does not take a list, but a `my_val` (or `expr` as the type seems to actually be). You have to use the `MAX` constructor to create such a value from the list: `eval (MAX (my_hd2 :: my_tl))`. But now you'll also get an error on `eval(i)`, because `i` (or `my_hd::my_tl.tl` from your original code) is not a `my_val` either. And if you just wrap that in `MAX` the function will recurse infinitely since you pass it the same value every time. That's a logic error you need to fix.